# Performance issues with larger data sets ng2-table

Tags: angular5

Has anyone tried using ng2-table with larger datasets, like over 1,00,000 records or 6MB? I'm noticing a lag in the filter, sort and search features when the data set exceeds this amount. I tried a test with the demo site and copied/paste the demo table-data to 100k records and even there you get about 7 - 9 second lag when doing sort and filter.

Sharing link `https://valor-software.com/ng2-table/`

Can someone help me for this